# How to use css Counter Increment

Tags: html, css

How to use css Counter Increment on only specific paragraph as it got applied to all the other paragraph in my document.

here's my current code:

```
    div.Counter{

counter-reset: my-counter ; 
}
h2::before {
    content: "Chapter" counter(my-counter) " : ";
    counter-increment: my-counter 1;
    color: blue;
}  
h2{counter-reset: subsection;
}
p::before{
      content: counter(my-counter) "." counter(subsection) "." ;
      counter-increment: subsection;
      color: red;
      margin-right: 5px;

}

}
```

Comment: Can you create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: add some more info to your question to debug your issue. it will be good if you can add an example including *HTML, CSS & Javascript* or create a **JSFiddle**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving the specific paragraph a class or id like shown below:

```
<p class="counterParagraph">This is a paragraph</p>
```

and editing your css

```
p.counterParagraph::before{
    content: counter(my-counter) "." counter(subsection) "." ;
    counter-increment: subsection;
    color: red;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```